# How to repeatedly update the same table using shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I have a shiny app that uses modules. In this app there are several drop downs with choices that need to be populated in a table. The first drop down relates to the second and gives the row filter to change the value of the second dropdown in the second column of the table, however the values in the first drop down should not change the values in first column of the table.

The table should first automatically populate with the default values of the drop downs (these vary so this cant be hard coded). The user of the app will look at choices and click the update button when they want a change to happen in the table. It is not obvious from this reproducible example but in the larger app the user will need to continuously update the table from the last update they did, not just send a full table of data to repopulate the whole thing. I know how to use the values from the drop downs to populate a table once, but I am having trouble understanding how I can store a table (or any object) somewhere so it can be accessed and updated continuously.

In case the description is not totally clear, I expect a table like this to appear on initialization:

[image: default table]

then if I change dropdown 2 to 'b' and click update table I expect it to look like this:

[image: first update]

finally if I change dropdown 1 to 'sandwich' and then change dropdown 2 to 'a' and click update table, I expect the table to look like this:

[image: last update]

Below is the code for a minimal example and in the `TabButtonServer` module you will see my best attempt at getting this to work but it does not. As mentioned above the crux of the issue is I don't know how I am supposed to store the table when its updated so that it can be referenced again later. I very much appreciate any help someone could offer.

```
## first drop down
ChooseUI1 <- function(id) {
  
  selectInput(NS(id, "choice1"),
              label=NULL,
              choices=c("foo", "bar", "ham", "sandwich"))
  
}

ChooseServer1 <- function(id) {

  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    reactive({
      input$choice1
    })
    
  })
}


## second drop down
ChooseUI2 <- function(id) {
  
  selectInput(NS(id, "choice2"),
              label=NULL,
              choices=c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
  
}

ChooseServer2 <- function(id) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    reactive({
      input$choice2
    })
    
  })
}


## button to change table
TabButtonUi <- function(id){
  
  actionButton(NS(id, "tab_change"),
               label="Update Table")
  
}

TabButtonServer <- function(id, c1, c2) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(c1))
  stopifnot(is.reactive(c2))
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    start_table <- reactive({
      cbind.data.frame(col1=c("foo", "bar", "ham", "sandwich"),
                       col2=c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    })
    
    new_table <- data.frame(col1=character(), col2=character())
    output_change <- eventReactive(input$tab_change, {
      
      if(input$tab_change == 0) {
        new_table <- start_table()
      } else {
        new_table[new_table[ , "col1"] == c1(), "col2"] <<- c2()
      }
      new_table
      
    }, ignoreNULL=FALSE)
    
    
    reactive({
      output_change()
    })
    
  })
}



## view table
viewTabUi <- function(id){
  tableOutput(NS(id, "view_tab"))
}

viewTabServer <- function(id, tab) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(tab))
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$view_tab <- renderTable(tab())
    
  })
}


## the app
ui <- navbarPage(
  title="test",
  tabPanel(title="first page",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               ChooseUI1("c1"),
               ChooseUI2("c2"),
               TabButtonUi("tab"),
               viewTabUi("view_tab")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               
             )
           )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  c1 <- ChooseServer1("c1")
  c2 <- ChooseServer2("c2")
  tab <- TabButtonServer("tab", c1, c2)
  viewTabServer("view_tab", tab)
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do is to use `reactiveValues()` object as shown below.

```
## first drop down
ChooseUI1 <- function(id) {
  
  selectInput(NS(id, "choice1"),
              label=NULL,
              choices=c("foo", "bar", "ham", "sandwich"))
  
}

ChooseServer1 <- function(id) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    reactive({
      input$choice1
    })
    
  })
}


## second drop down
ChooseUI2 <- function(id) {
  
  selectInput(NS(id, "choice2"),
              label=NULL,
              choices=c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
  
}

ChooseServer2 <- function(id) {
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    reactive({
      input$choice2
    })
    
  })
}


## button to change table
TabButtonUi <- function(id){
  
  actionButton(NS(id, "tab_change"),
               label="Update Table")
  
}

TabButtonServer <- function(id, c1, c2) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(c1))
  stopifnot(is.reactive(c2))
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    start_table <-  cbind.data.frame(col1=c("foo", "bar", "ham", "sandwich"),
                                     col2=c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    
    rv <- reactiveValues(df=NULL)
    
    observeEvent(input$tab_change, {
      
      if(input$tab_change == 0) {
        rv$df <- start_table
      } else {
        rv$df[rv$df$col1 == c1(), "col2"] <<- c2()
      }
      
    }, ignoreNULL=FALSE)
    
    reactive({
      rv$df
    })
    
  })
}


## view table
viewTabUi <- function(id){
  tableOutput(NS(id, "view_tab"))
}

viewTabServer <- function(id, tab) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(tab))
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$view_tab <- renderTable(tab())
    
  })
}


## the app
ui <- navbarPage(
  title="test",
  tabPanel(title="first page",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               ChooseUI1("c1"),
               ChooseUI2("c2"),
               TabButtonUi("tab"),
               viewTabUi("view_tab")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               
             )
           )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  c1 <- ChooseServer1("c1")
  c2 <- ChooseServer2("c2")
  tab <- TabButtonServer("tab", c1, c2)
  viewTabServer("view_tab", tab)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Alternative answer:** To take advantage of the modules programming, you could use one `selectInput` module multiple times as shown below

```
####  drop down
ChooseUI1 <- function(id) {

  selectInput(NS(id, "choice1"), label=NULL, choices=NULL)

}

ChooseServer1 <- function(id,df_col) {

  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    updateSelectInput(session, "choice1", choices= unique(df_col))
    
    reactive({
      input$choice1
    })

  })
}


## button to change table
TabButtonUi <- function(id){

  actionButton(NS(id, "tab_change"), label="Update Table")

}

TabButtonServer <- function(id, c1, c2, start_table) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(c1))
  stopifnot(is.reactive(c2))

  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    rv <- reactiveValues(df=NULL)

    observeEvent(input$tab_change, {

      if(input$tab_change == 0) {
        rv$df <- start_table
      } else {
        rv$df[rv$df$col1 == c1(), "col2"] <<- c2()
      }
      
    }, ignoreNULL=FALSE)
    
    reactive({ rv$df })

  })
}


## view table
viewTabUi <- function(id){
  tableOutput(NS(id, "view_tab"))
}

viewTabServer <- function(id, tab) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(tab))

  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

    output$view_tab <- renderTable(tab())

  })
}


## the app
ui <- navbarPage(
  title="test",
  tabPanel(title="first page",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               ChooseUI1("c1"),
               ChooseUI1("c2"),
               TabButtonUi("tab"),
               viewTabUi("view_tab")
             ),
             mainPanel()
           )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  df <-  cbind.data.frame(col1=c("foo", "bar", "ham", "sandwich"),
                          col2=c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                          stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  cc1 <- ChooseServer1("c1",df$col1)
  cc2 <- ChooseServer1("c2",df$col2)
  tab <- TabButtonServer("tab", cc1, cc2, df)
  viewTabServer("view_tab", tab)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @YBS. Can you tell me how this works? does `reactiveValues()` crate a list of reactives that are outside the module so they exist for the next time its called?

Comment: Please see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/reactiveValues.html) for definition.  Basically, you can modify this object in an observer, and it is available outside the observer. Also, it exists for the next call. You cannot modify a reactive object, once it is created.